# Shuffle product formula for coproduct

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, hopf-algebras, coproduct

I'm studying the coproduct $\Delta$ defined on a tensor algebra $T(V)$ and its action on tensor products of elements from a vector space $V$. The coproduct is given by $\Delta(v) = v \boxtimes 1 + 1 \boxtimes v$ for any $v \in V$, and extended as an algebra homomorphism over $T(V)$  (through the universal property of $T(V)$). I've encountered the following formula that expresses $\Delta$ applied to a tensor product of $m$ elements:

$$
\Delta(v_1)\otimes\cdots\otimes\Delta(v_m) = \sum_{p=0}^m \; \sum_{\sigma\in\mathrm{Sh}(p,m-p)} \;
\left(v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{\sigma(p)}\right) \boxtimes 
\left(v_{\sigma(p+1)}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{\sigma(m)}\right)
$$

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume the formula holds for a tensor product of $m-1$ elements.

**Inductive Step:** To prove the formula for $m$ elements, we consider the action of $\Delta$ on the tensor product of $m$ elements and then apply the inductive hypothesis.

Starting from the inductive hypothesis, the application of $\Delta(v_m)$ yields:

$$
\sum_{p=0}^{m-1} \sum_{\sigma\in\mathrm{Sh}(p,m-1-p)} \left[ (v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_p) \otimes v_m \boxtimes (v_{p+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{m-1}) \otimes 1 + (v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_p) \otimes 1 \boxtimes (v_{p+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{m-1}) \otimes v_m \right]
$$

We wish to show this equals:

$$
\sum_{p=0}^m \; \sum_{\sigma\in\mathrm{Sh}(p,m-p)} \;
\left(v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{\sigma(p)}\right) \boxtimes 
\left(v_{\sigma(p+1)}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{\sigma(m)}\right)
$$

I find it hard to see why this last step works. How does one rigorously justify this equality?

Maybe it has something to do with the [inductive definition of the shuffle product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffle_algebra#Shuffle_product)?

Comment: Even a general hint would be welcome